# SQLite delete for Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone explain how the delete actually works, as the documentation isn't providing me with enough help. What i'm trying to do is delete all rows from my table where the date matches the one i provide in the delete method.

This is what i've tried:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = appts.getWritableDatabase();

    String whereclause = "WHERE DATE = ";

    long seldate = calendar.getDate()/1000;
    String datestodelete = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(new java.util.Date (seldate*1000));

    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, whereclause, datestodelete);
```

But it says String String String isnt accepted for that method, what would i put in instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The third argument should be of type `String[]`, not `String`:

```
public int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Your `table`, `whereClause`, and `whereArgs` should be formatted as follows:

```
table = "table_name";
whereClause = "col1 = ? AND col2 = ?";
whereArgs = new String[] { date1, date2 };
```

In other words, the values in the `String[]` will replace the `?`s in your `whereClause`. Also note that you should omit the `WHERE` at the beginning of your `whereClause` (this will be added automatically when Android performs the delete).

Comment: As i said i have read this but it is un clear to me. I understand where to put my table name but i dont know how to form my whereClause or what it means by asking for String[]

Comment: Ok getting there slowly, what purpose does the String[] serve for this method?

Comment: It is just a way to organize the values that you wish to insert into your "where clause". If you wanted, you could set `whereArgs = null` and then set `whereClause = "col1 = date1 AND col2 = date2"`. Both will give you identical results... they are just different ways of performing the same operation. That being said, with complex "where clauses", replacing `?`s with the values in a String array is much more convenient than hardcoding the values in a single `whereClause` string (at least in my opinion).